# Disable Strong Password Front end Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

want to know if any way can disable strong password restriction on Frontend of login widget ? Image Attach .. Thanks in Advance !!!
[image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific what you are using for front end login , is there any specific plugin you are using ??

Comment: hi thanks .. i am using woocommerce login shortcode only ! but didn't find way to disable from admin ...